# Is there a Magic card that rearranges the stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm thinking of a card that can do this:

1. I have [Niv-Mizzet, Parun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNiv-Mizzet%2c%20Parun%5d) on the battlefield.
2. Opponent casts [Aether Gust](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAether%20Gust%5d) on Niv-Mizzet. Niv-Mizzet triggers.
3. Usually the trigger would resolve before Aether Gust. Instead I cast [mystery card] (or activate [mystery ability]) which rearranges the stack to make Aether Gust resolve first, which allows Niv-Mizzet to draw itself.

Does the mystery card/ability exist? Using the [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/) database, I'm not getting results for the words "rearrange" and "stack", but it's possible I'm looking for the wrong words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No, there is no such card.**

[This search](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[stack]+![split]+![%22end%20the%20turn%22]&set=+![%22Unglued%22]+![%22Unhinged%22]+![%22Mystery%20Booster%22]+![%22Unsanctioned%22]+![%22Unstable%22]) lists all cards interacting with the stack, excluding Split Second, ending the turn, and cards from Un-sets.

Answer (score 8):

No card rearranges the stack, but you could copy the Aether Gust with a spell (e.g. [Fork](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202493)) or ability (a leveled up [Echo Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEcho%20Mage%5d)) so that you can still draw Niv-Mizzet. Note that Fork would trigger Niv-Mizzet again, and the original Aether Gust will fizzle because it doesn't have a valid target anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The mystery booster playtest card [Queue of Beetles](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bQueue%20of%20Beetles%5d) technically rearranges the stack as a game mechanic overall, though you need to cast it with flash to rearrange a particular stack in the process of resolving.

Comment: It only changes the order of evaluation, though. New additions still get handled last.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but aren't new additions usually handled first?  So wouldn't new additions being handled last be rearranging the stack?

Comment: You're right. The positions on the stack stay the same but the order of evaluation of the stack is reversed for the turn.

Answer (score 0):

[Animate Spell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnimate%20Spell%5d) moves a spell from the stack to the battlefield,
[Stack of Paperwork](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStack%20of%20Paperwork%5d) makes combat damage use the stack,
and [Sudden Substitution](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSudden%20Substitution%5d) changes a spell's owner and targets.

Comment: Animate Spell and Stack of Paperwork were made exclusively for Chaos Draft and are not Standard-legal. (They even say "Not for constructed play" on them.) Even ignoring that, though, they mess with things on the stack or remove things from the stack (a.la. countering) - they do not change the order of things on the stack as OP is asking for and would not produce the effect OP is describing.

Comment: Removal of an element inside the stack alters the order in which spells are executed (1 sooner for those below it).

Comment: It doesn't "alter" the order since those spells are still executed in the same order, it only changes the spells' timing. Changing the order would be like having two spells on the stack where A resolves before B and changing it so now B resolves before A. Order and timing are different concepts, otherwise this question could be answered by simply naming off one of [hundreds counter spells](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[target]+[spell]+[counter]).

Comment: Okay, then remove B from the stack to the battlefield and then back to the stack.

Comment: The only way that would work is if, after Animate Spell resolves (which, again, is about as non-Standard a card as it gets) another spell removes it from the battlefield, at which point it can be recast back onto the stack. However, it's up to the spell's original owner to do so, and I doubt that OP's opponent would be so accomodating.

Comment: Pairing a counterspell with a copy effect would come the closest to what OP is describing, but strictly speaking, that's still not affecting the order of the stack. That's just making so instead of the stack changing from A-B to B-A, it becomes A-B-C (where C is a copy of A) and then B-C after A is countered. Glorfindel's answer already covers this interpretation, which achieves OP's desired effect but not in the way OP is asking for.